# How to remove items from +New admin menu?

Tags: wp-admin, admin, hooks, admin-menu

I would like to limit the +New admin menu to only show the single sub menu Event ("Veranstaltung").
Basically the users are allowed to create other items as well but not from that +New menu.

[image: +New Admin Menu]

I already tried it with "Adminimize" plugin as this can remove the other items but it will leave the new media link intact once you click directly "+New".

[image: +New Admin Menu - link still there]

I already added some other logic to remove items from the left admin menu like:

```
function remove_menus() {

    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=mdocs-posts');
 }
 add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

But I can't get how to modify the +New. Any hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To hide everything (menu and submenu)-**

```
function wpse_260669_remove_new_content(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-content' );
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse_260669_remove_new_content' );
```

**To hide specific menu/submenu item(s)-**

```
function wpse_260669_remove_new_content_items(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-post' ); // hides post CPT
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-product' ); // hides product CPT
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-page' ); // hides page CPT
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-media' ); // hides media
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse_260669_remove_new_content_items' );
```

**So, the basic rule is-**

```
function your_boo_bar_function() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'your-unique-menu-id' );
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'your_boo_bar_function' );
```

**Add a new menu-**

```
function wpse_260669_add_menu(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node(
        array(
            'id'        => 'google-menu',
            'title'     => 'Google',
            'href'      => 'http://google.com',
            'parent'    => 'new-content', // so, it'll be set as a child of 'new-content'. remove this to use this as a parent menu
            'meta'      => array( 'class' => 'my-custom-class' ),
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse_260669_add_menu' );
```

**Update an existing menu-**

If you want to update an existing menu item, just add a new item using the ID of your desired menu.

To update +New ('content-new'), use this code-

```
function wpse_260669_update_menu(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node(
        array(
            'id'    => 'new-content', // id of an existing menu
            'href'  => 'your_new_url_goes_here', // set new URL
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse_260669_update_menu' );
```

**How to get menu ID-**

The easiest way is to inspect element with Firebug and take the ID. See this screenshot-

[image: How to get menu ID]

Navigate to your desired menu item and get the string next to `wp-admin-bar-`

Comment: Hi mukto90, thanks for your explanation. I see that your approach removes items from the +New menu, but it still leaves the link of the "originally" first item once +New is clicked. If you would remove "Post" menu item in your screenshot the +New itself will still link to post-new.php.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. +New is hyperlinked to the first item `post-new.php`. So, what's your expectation?

Comment: I removed the first item (in my case "media-new.php"). But the link still shows up behind +New. I want to achieve that +New links to the new first item (previously second item)

Comment: Well. I have updated my answer. please check.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @mukto90's answer, the following adds a menu to the toolbar that lists the node id (what you need to pass to `$wp_admin_bar->remove_node()`) of all *other* nodes in the toolbar.

```
add_action ('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'add_all_node_ids_to_toolbar'), 99999) ;

function
add_all_node_ids_to_toolbar ()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar ;

    if (!current_user_can ('manage_options')) {
        // allow only "admins" to have our menu
        return ;
        }

    $all_toolbar_nodes = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes () ;

    if (empty ($all_toolbar_nodes)) {
        // there are no top-level nodes, so bail
        return ;
        }

    // add our top-level menu to the toolbar
    $our_node_id = 'node_ids' ;
    $args = array (
        'id' => $our_node_id,
        'title' => "Node ID's",
        ) ;
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node ($args) ;

    // add all current Toolbar items to their parent node or to our top-level menu
    foreach ($all_toolbar_nodes as $node) {
        $args = array (
            'id' => "{$our_node_id}_{$node->id}", // prefix id with "node_id_" to make it a unique id
            'title' => $node->id,
            ) ;

        if (!(isset ($node->parent) && $node->parent)) {
            // the node has no parent, so add it to our top-level menu
            $args['parent'] = $our_node_id ;
            }
        else {
            // the node has a parent, so add it as a child to appropriate node in our menu
            $args['parent'] = "{$our_node_id}_{$node->parent}" ;
            }

        $wp_admin_bar->add_node ($args) ;
        }

    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to take advantage of the `show_in_admin_bar` property of post types.  When post types are registered (both built-ins and custom post types) they declare whether they "want" to be included in the "New" toolbar menu, ala

```
$args = array (
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true|false,
    ) ;
register_post_type ('post_type_name', $args) ;
```

So, for CPTs you register, if you don't want them to appear in the "New" toolbar menu, just set `'show_in_admin_bar' => false,`.  If `show_in_admin_bar` is not specified in `$args`, then it defaults to the value of `show_in_menu`.  See [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for details.

How about the built-ins?  You can remove those that you don't want with the following:

```
add_action ('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_from_toolbar_new') ;

function
remove_from_toolbar_new ()
{
    $allow_in_toolbar_new = array (
        'page', // if you don't want any built-ins, just make this an empty array
        ) ;

    $args = array (
        '_builtin' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        ) ;
    foreach (get_post_types ($args, 'objects') as $post_type) {
        if (in_array ($post_type->name, $allow_in_toolbar_new)) {
            continue ;
            }

        $post_type->set_props (array ('show_in_admin_bar' => false)) ;
        }

    return ;
}
```

See [get_post_types()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/) and [WP_Post_Type::set_props()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/set_props/) for details.

As far as I know, the only way to remove the "Users" item from the "New" toolbar menu is with the technique that @mukto90 mentions.