# How to remove an item from menu bar's +New menu based on User role

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar

I want to hide / remove a particular menu item from +New menu on admin menu bar based on specific user role. I referred to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260669/how-to-remove-items-from-new-admin-menu) post and tried what is suggested here but for me it did not work.

I have a user role **fuel-surcharge-editor**, which should not get access to Weather Alert content type (please see screenshot).

[image]

Both Fuel Surcharge and Weather Alert are custom post types. So from +New menu both are pointing to same location:

`http://vagrant.local/wp/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=fuel-surcharge`, with a different post_type.

I tried the following:

```
function remove_new_content_items(){
    if(current_user_can('fuel-surcharge-editor')) {
       global $wp_admin_bar;
       $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'post-new', 'weather_alert' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_new_content_items', 0 );
```

I also tried
`$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('post-new.php?post_type=weather_alert');` and `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('post-new.php', 'weather_alert');`

but none worked. How can I do this?

Comment: has user role **fuel-surcharge-editor** the capabilitie to create this CPT ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If CPT = Post type content, then yes. Actually I got the answer. It has to be `remove_node`, not `remove_menu`. Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node.

Comment: instead of removing the item in the "New" menu, it can be more intersting to remove the create capabilitie. if you just modify the menu, user can always go to the URL to create a "weather_alert"

Comment: So you mean remove_menu or remove_node does not actually blocks the accessibility permanently? Can you please suggest me some articles to read on about handling capabilities and how it is used to "remove menu"?